# Spring Boot/Spring Data. How to fill DB with encoded data using data.sql containing not encoded data

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-data-rest

I'm writing some kind of "hello-world" REST service with Spring Data Rest.

I have a simple @Entity class:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date birthDate;
    private String email;
    @Column(length = 60)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BCryptPasswordDeserializer.class)    
    private String password;
    // getters and setters
    }
```

As you can see, there's a @JsonDeserialize above password field so any password coming from client is encoded with BCryptPasswordEncoder before going to database. BTW I'm using H2 im-memory DB.

Implementation of BCryptPasswordDeserializer:

```java
public class BCryptPasswordDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(node.asText());
        return encodedPassword;
    }        
}
```

Also I have data.sql in my resources:

```
insert into user (id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, email, password)
values (1, 'Ivan', 'Ivanov', '1990-01-01', 'i.ivanov@test.test', '123567');
insert into user (id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, email, password)
values(2, 'Petr', 'Petrov', '1990-01-01', 'p.petrov@test.test', '123567');
insert into user (id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, email, password)
values(3, 'John', 'Cena', '1990-01-01', 'j.cena@test.test', '123567');
insert into user (id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, email, password)
values(4, 'Michael', 'Moore', '1990-01-01', 'm.moore@test.test', '123567');
insert into user (id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, email, password)
values(5, 'Trevor', 'Fassbender', '1990-01-01', 't.fassbender@test.test', '123567');
```

And there's my "problem": I need something that also will encode passwords from this file before inserting into table. Is there any way to do that? Or maybe there's some different way in Spring to fill database which allows to use encryption logic before inserting data?

Comment: https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator 1234567 -> $2a$04$RZsL0kD/VHs0UU2maqA86OK1H08A18/78aooPcZ1zuLVH0TuWszkG

Comment: @Cepr0 thank you, but I don't want to hardcode that thing :)

Comment: You already did this.

Comment: @Cepr0 well yeah, let's say it's just temporary solution. Maybe there's some different way in Spring to fill database which allows to use encryption logic before inserting data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create Spring component that uses the repository to insert the data after startup.

Something like this:

```
@Component
class UserCreator {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userRepository.save(new User('Ivan', 'Ivanov', '1990-01-01', 'i.ivanov@test.test', '123567'));
        // etc
    }
}
```

To control whether the `UserCreator` is used or not (you probably don't want to do this in your production environment), you may add a `@Profile` annotation to the class. Or you insert the data only if the `User` database table is empty ... (or whatever condition you want).

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed, except It has to be

    new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("123456")

instead of simple '123456'

Comment: And also there's have to be an empty constructor in @Entity class for some reason. Without it even passwords from clients don't encode.

Comment: How would you do this in production environment?